# What is wrong with my .json file?

Tags: json, adobe-brackets

```
{
"fonts.fontSize": "14px",
"fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
"themes.theme": "daugther.of.obsidian",
"noDistractions": false,
"wordWrap": true,

"BracketsNewProjectExtension.newProjectsFolder": "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/team2019site", 

"closeBrackets": false,

"closeTags": {
    "whenOpening": false,
    "whenClosing": false,
   } 
}
```

Brackets is saying this preferences file is invalid upon startup and none of the preferences are getting applied.

Thanks for the help and have a nice day.

Comment: you've got raw unicode in there. json requires those to be encoded as `\uXXXX` escape sequences. and you have a trailing `,` on the final `false`, which is outright illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonlint.com to validate your json. it seems that you have an extra "," after whenClosing.